# Como intercalar una misma fila entre las filas de una matriz en python?

Tags: python, numpy, matriz

Como intercalar una misma fila entre las filas de una matriz en python?

```
mat1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 8], [7, 6, 8, 9]])

fila = [3, 2]
```

con:

```
for j in range(0,3): 
    print(3, 2)
    print(m1)
```

se ve así:
3 2

```
[[181, 325, 337], [182, 326, 338], [183, 327, 339]]
3 2
[[181, 325, 337], [182, 326, 338], [183, 327, 339]]
3 2
[[181, 325, 337], [182, 326, 338], [183, 327, 339]]
```

pero para que se vea algo así:

```
m1=[[1, 2, 3, 4],
    [3, 2],
    [4, 5, 6, 8],
    [3, 2],
    [7, 6, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Dada la matriz, tú puedes recorrerla mediante: `m1[i][j]`, donde `i` sería la sublista dentro de la matriz y `j` sería el valor dentro de la sublista `m1[i]`

Además, para tener un valor de lista, tienes que especificar con `[]`, por lo que sería `print([3, 2])` o `print(fila)`.

Finalmente, el código quedaría tal que así

```
for i in range(len(m1)):  #el len se refiere a quan larga es la matriz/lista
    print([3, 2]) #o tambien print(fila)
    print(m1[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Acá va la respuesta cavernícola, que seguramente será superada...

```
mat = [ [1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 8], [7, 6, 8, 9] ] 
fila = [3, 2]

muy = []
for i in range( len( mat ) ):
    muy.append( mat[ i ])
    if( i != len( mat ) -1 ):
        muy.append( fila )
        
print( muy )
```

Después de mucha "lucha" lo hacemos con compresión de listas...

```
muy = []
largo = len( mat ) -1
[ ( muy.append( mat[ i ] ), muy.append( fila )) if i < largo else muy.append( mat[ i ] ) for i in range( len( mat )) ]

print(muy)
```